# Can't get Checkboxes to stop displaying a hidden Div

Tags: javascript

I have inserted some javascript to get two checkboxes in particular to display a hidden Div when they are checked and to make that Div disappear when they are unchecked. The issue I am having is that all of the other checkboxes are making the Div appear when they are checked. Now they do not fade in or fade out like the original two checkboxes are supposed to do. Instead they other checkboxes just make the hidden Div appear only. How do I prevent the other checkboxes from influencing the Div.

the page is http://asilverwareaffair.net/_NEW/request-a-quote/

the correct checkboxes are:

> Wedding Reception (Ceremony is off site)
>   Wedding Reception (Ceremony on site)

they are located under "Type of Event" in the "Event Details" section

the Div: `id="weddingselect" class="hide"` is hidden but appear when any checkbox is checked. However it properly fades in and out when the correct checkboxes above are checked and unchecked. What would cause all the other checkboxes on the page to make the "weddingselect" Div become visable and how do I stop them?

Here is the JavaScript I used to make the div fade in and out with the Wedding Reception checkboxes:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#wedchk1').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) 
        //  ^
           $('#weddingselect').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            $('#weddingselect').fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $('#wedchk2').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) 
        //  ^
           $('#weddingselect').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            $('#weddingselect').fadeOut('slow');
    }); 
});
</script>
```

**HOWEVER**: I don't think my javascript has anything to do with it because if I remove all javascript the checkboxes on the page still make the Hidden div appear when they are checked... it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following code in your `custom.js`:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            var chkVal = (this.value);
            if(chkVal="Wedding Reception"){
                $('#weddingselect').show();
                //$('#weddingselect').css()
            }else{
                $('#weddingselect').hide();
            }

        }
        //$('#weddingselect').hide();
});
```

That's why it's "working" even if you remove the mentioned script.

Comment: Thank you! Ok now this is a wordpress site. How do I gain access to the custom.js file. I have spent that last 30 mins trying or at the very least could I write something to override that line of code? Thank you so much for your help so far.

Comment: You're welcome. Since it's called "custom" I think you can access it. I've never used wordpress, so I can't help you with that. But in the worst case, you could change the id of weddingselect to something else to prevent the div from showing.

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this)` not `this`.

`this`is for native Javascript, `$(this)` is for jQuery.

Also use `$(this).is(':checked')` instead of `$(this).checked.`.
And lastly, use {} for `if else` statements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#wedchk1').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           $('#weddingselect').fadeIn('slow');
        }
        else {
            $('#weddingselect').fadeOut('slow');
        } 
    });
    $('#wedchk2').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           $('#weddingselect').fadeIn('slow');
        }
        else {
            $('#weddingselect').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, however I am still running into the issue where the other checkboxes on the page are making the #weddingselect Div appear. I can tell the javascript works for #wedchk1 and #wedchk2 because #weddingselect not only appears/disappears but it fades in/out as the javascript intends. I don't understand why all the other checkboxes on that page are making #weddingselect appear... I only want #wedchk1 and #wedchk2 to make the #weddingselect to appear otherwise it must remain hidden. Thanks again.